# jest code coverage overlay not showing up in vscode anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, jestjs, vscode-jest

It had previously been working. All I had to do is: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` and run `Jest: Toggle Coverage`. Sometimes I had to manually trigger the test run for the file I wanted to have a code coverage overlay.

I made sure I'm

- viewing a file which had a test and
- didn't have full coverage
- that the extension has code coverage toggled on:

[image]

I let all tests run, restarted vscode, enabled autorun, but it all did not help.

```
jest@29.3.1
vscode-jest v5.2.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned out someone had manually disabled `jest.autoRun.watch` in .vscode/settings.json which is part of the git repo of our project:

```
"jest.autoRun": { "watch": false, "onSave": "test-file" },
```

changing it to

```
"jest.autoRun": { "watch": true, "onSave": "test-file" },
```

made the overlay reappear.

Setting `jest.autoRun.watch` to false in the workspace, overwrites the global and user level settings, and without `jest.autoRun.watch`, jest does not seem to display the code coverage overlay, even if you run the test onSave.

Also the UI of the `vscode-jest` extension is a bit misleading, as it lets you toggle on and off the autorun with a little button (see above screenshot), but it won't have an effect on the `jest.autoRun.watch: false`, if it is set in the workspace's .vscode/settings.json.

But you can actually see the current active setting in the `vscode-jest` extensions UI:

When you have turned it off with the toggle button:
[image]

Turned on with the toggle button, but `jest.autoRun.watch: false`:
[image]

Turned on with the toggle button, and `jest.autoRun.watch: true`
[image]

> **Only the last setting will work to display code coverage overlays as of `vscode-jest v5.2.3`!**

As I didn't find something about this in the documentation, I will probably not be the only one, who runs into this.